# Maven packaging for websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere, ear

I am trying to build an EAR file - Which can be deployed in IBM websphere server.
This is an existing struts appliation, i am trying to mavenize it.
This project contains two folders

```
   1. web
   2. webEAR
```

web is actually for war file and webEAR folder for the EAR file, `web` contains all the code, and `webEAR` is a kind of a wrapper.

Steps I have already done are below

1. IDE - Eclipse
2. Java version - 1.7
3. Convereted both web and webEAR to Maven - (Configure to Maven)
4. edited the POM.XML like below

```js
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.comp.web</groupId>
 <artifactId>web</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>WEB</name>
 <description>WEB</description>
```

```
added all relevant jar files - which are in lib folder as below (sample)
```

```js
<dependency>
 <groupId>jarfile</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>  
<systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEBINF/lib/com.ibm.jarfile.jar</systemPat>
 </dependency>
```

Now i dont have any errors in the eclipse, and I can run the application by right clicking the webEAR folder -> Run in Server, It works.

but I am not sure, how to create a EAR file , which has the war file, so that I can deploy in the WAS server dev environment.

Can someone show me a way I can do this. currently there is no `POM.xml` in the `webEAR` maven folder

P.S - I am not a Java developer. This is a first maven related project I am assigned to. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module should have `<packaging>ear</packaging>`.

In the dependencies for this ear module ( Use a new module to build the ear ) include your war module as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.comp.webGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>war-artifact</artifactId>
    <version> war-version</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

In the build plugins for this ear module include the maven-ear-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>web</finalName>
        <version>versionNumber</version>
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>${basedir}/src/main/application/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.comp.webGroupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>war-artifact</artifactId>
                <uri>web.war</uri>
                <bundleFileName>web.war</bundleFileName>
                <contextRoot>/applicationName</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add any specific configuration values as required.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are suggesting a plugin which is ten years old?

Comment: According to my knowledge and experiences this was the best solution I could provided.

Comment: @khmarbaise Is there an alternative? That seems to be *the* Maven way to build ears. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html (unless you're referring specifically to the 2.3.2 version?)

Comment: I explicitly referenced to the version. Furthermore why are you using so much configuration. Usually the best is to define the packaging "ear" and define the version only and let maven-ear-plugin do it's work. Best is to have a separate module for the `ear` and just define the dependencies...

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought you have asked why using this plugin, I did not notice the old version. I haven't explicitly said it is needed a new module. I will update the answer.